# Which printer software driver should I use?

Tags: printing, software, driver, airprint, cups

When adding a printer in OS X, and assuming the printer is AirPrint enabled, which driver should I use: 1. the AirPrint driver or 2. the CUPS driver for that specific printer?

[image]

My assumption is that while AirPrint is easy to use, it also must be generic enough to support a wide range of printers and a limited number of functions. Thus, while I can easily print with the AirPrint driver, I won't have access to all of the printer's functions and **would be better off using the CUPS driver** for that specific printer if I intend to print from that printer often or need more control over the printing process.

Anyone have documentation to support/refute my assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter. I've used both with an Epson multifunction printer/scanner and I have not lacked for any features with AirPrint.